# How to insert one column of data from one table into another?

Tags: r, matrix, rstudio

I am trying to add this table:

```
#       [,1]
#[1,] -0.870  8
#[2,] -0.750  7  
#[3,]  2.290  2
#[4,] -0.050  5
#[5,]  0.355  4
#[6,] -0.895  9
#[7,]  3.290  1 
#[8,] -0.510  6 
#[9,]  0.430  3
#[10,] -3.290 10
```

Into this the respective "predAwayScore" and "predHomeScore" columns in my data frame.
[image]

I want to insert the left hand column of the first data set (-.87, -.75, etc.) into the appropriate cells. The right hand side of that data set (8,7,2,etc.) corresponds to the letter on the data frame that the value needs to be entered. (For instance, AwayTeam E = 5 = -.05)

I am unsure how to insert one column into another data frame, and how to refer to the corresponding letter guide that is attached.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a named vector, use that to match the 'AwayTeam', 'HomeTeam' values to get the corresponding scores and assign those values to the columns 'predAwayScore', 'predHomeScore'

```
nm1 <- setNames(m1[,1], LETTERS[m1[,2]])
df1$predAwayScore <- nm1[df1[['AwayTeam']]]
df1$predHomeScore <- nm1[df1[['HomeTeam']]]
df1
#  Week AwayTeam HomeTeam predAwayScore predHomeScore
#1    3        E        A        -0.050          3.29
#2    3        A        F         3.290         -0.51
#3    4        H        E        -0.870         -0.05
#4    4        I        A        -0.895          3.29
#5    5        F        C        -0.510          0.43
#6    5        F        J        -0.510         -3.29
```

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(-0.87, -0.75, 2.29, -0.05, 0.3555, -0.895, 3.29, 
-0.51, 0.43, -3.29, 8, 7, 2, 5, 4, 9, 1, 6, 3, 10), .Dim = c(10L, 
2L))

df1 <- structure(list(Week = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), AwayTeam = c("E", 
"A", "H", "I", "F", "F"), HomeTeam = c("A", "F", "E", "A", "C", 
"J")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This more or less solved my issues.